# Sed to replace lowercase and capital strings

Tags: sed, scripting

I'm trying to use sed to replace every instance of **old** in the file with **new**.  Now it works with lowercase strings, but I need it to replace certain strings that are capitalized.  For Example replace **OLD** with **NEW**. I know sed can do this, but I can't get it quite right?

```
for file in .; do
  cat $file
  sed 's/old/new/g' $file | tee $file
done
```

Comment: if you want to replace "OLD", why are you searching for "old"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know about the `i` / `I` flag to the `s` command (GNU extension, though)?

Comment: I have some idea about it, if I'm correct it you put `i / I` after the `s`? I have very little experience sed, if I'm wrong tell me.

Comment: No, adjacent to the `g`.

Comment: adding /I would make the *search* case-insensitive, but wouldn't the replacement remain "new" versus the desired "NEW"?

Comment: Oh Ok,  that explains why I couldn't get it too work, now it's working thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To replace "old" with "new" and "OLD" with "NEW", just tell sed to do both:

```
for file in ./*; do
  cat "$file"
  sed -i -e 's/old/new/g; s/OLD/NEW/g' "$file"
done
```

Don't forget to quote the variables, in case you have a file named `some filename` (with spaces, newlines, or tabs in them). I also added `-i`, a GNU sed extension, given that [you indicated that you could use the GNU /i flag extension](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/477043/sed-to-replace-lowercase-and-capital-strings#comment871893_477047), to tell sed to edit the file in-place instead of relying on `tee` and buffers to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use perl:

```
$ cat file
old news
OLD news
old Old oLD news
older news
```

```
$ perl -pe 's{(old)}{ ($tmp = $1) =~ tr/OLDold/NEWnew/; $tmp }ieg' file
new news
NEW news
new New nEW news
newer news
```

That uses the `s///` operator to do search and replace, and in the replacement, it *transliterates* the characters from "old" to "new", preserving the individual characters' case. This only works because "old" and "new" are the same string length.

I need to use a temp variable because `$1` is a read-only value.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the strings are of the same size, all this commands will work:

```
<infile sed    'y/OLDold/NEWnew/' >outfile
<infile tr     'OLDold'  'NEWnew' >outfile
        sed -i 'y/OLDold/NEWnew/' infile
```